# lectura de datos con python

Tags: python

Solicito de su ayuda con lo siguiente, estoy realizando una consulta a una base de datos sqlServer usando python, la consulta se ejecuta correctamente pero los datos llegan dentro de un arreglo o un diccionario creo yo y no logro manipularlos.                                                                              el codigo es el siguiente

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
q = cursor.execute("""SELECT indice
                             codemp,
                             telefono,
                             horfingest,
                             asesor,
                             val_indicad,
                             codind,
                             indicad,
                             desccod01,
                             fecha_Cargue,
                             Cliente,
                             clienteId
                            FROM Gestion_Bi.dbo.GestionBitexfec
                         WHERE CONVERT(DATE,horfingest) = '{0}'
                    """.format(fecha))
rows = q.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows)
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
[10000,31032132,2020-02-23 10:01:01,]
```

Quiero poder utilizar esta informacion para realizar un insert en otra base de datos.

Comment: Si el conector que usas sigue las especificaciones de PEP 249, casi seguro que si, fetchall retorna una lista de tuplas, en la que cada tupla es una fila resultante de la query con los valores de cada columna. En principio no debería haber ningún problema para pasarlo a Pandas.DataFrame. ¿El resultado que muestras es el contenido de rows?

Comment: FJSevilla gracias por tu pronta respuesta, el resultado obtenido es una muestra de los rows, lo que pasa es que no se como puedo convertir eso para para usarlo en un insert en otra base de datos.